# CodeIgniter :: Error in bootstrap script: Error: Call to undefined method CI_Hooks::call_hook()

Tags: codeigniter, phpunit

I've been strugling to make the PhpUnitTest  https://phpunit.de/,work with codeIgniter 3.
I've corrected them all, till this last one, I'm hopeless about this unittest working with my project.

I faced multiple errors,

````
Call to undefined method CI_Hooks::call_hook() ```



Can you help or suggest any Solution please.
````

Comment: have you fixed the issue? I am still struggling with it

Comment: I did yes, but I cant tell wot I've made as a change on my project to make it.
I've done a lot of changes I can't remember. if you want I can make my project online on github and take a look.

Comment: Thank you so much, I fixed my problem too, in here https://github.com/kenjis/ci-phpunit-test/issues/399

Comment: PErfect, happy to know that.